# how to write Junit test case which covers catch block during code coverage?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

below is code and I want to know how can I write a JUnit test so that my coverage can cover catch block

```
import com.pkg.ClothBrandQuery;

Public class MapBrand implements SomeInterface{
   public Brand mapThisBrands(final ClothBrand clothBrand) {

     Brand brand = new Brand();
     try{
        defaultBrand = clothBrandQuery.getClothBrandMethod(ProjectConstants.DEFAULT_BRAND_KEY);
     }
     catch(Exception e){
        logger.fatal("Database error occurred retrieving default cloth brands", e);
        System.exit(2);
     }                              
             if(defaultBrand != null && defaultBrand != clothBrand){
        brand.setBrandName(clothBrand.getBrandName());
        brand.setCompanyName(clothBrand.getCompanyName());
        brand.setBackgroundColor(clothBrand.getBackgroundColor());
             }
             else{
                brand.setBrandName(defaultBrand.getBrandName());
        brand.setCompanyName(defaultBrand.getCompanyName());
        brand.setBackgroundColor(defaultBrand.getBackgroundColor());
             }
    }
}
```

I am able to write test method for mapThisBrands to test brand object but I dont know how I can test defaultBrand object and how I write a testcase where catch block will get executed.

Comment: Avoid using `System.exit()` anywhere except the top-level `main()` method with the only purpose to return an exit code. Always use exceptions in all other cases. See http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=86.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to test exception with junit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972867/unable-to-test-exception-with-junit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that `System.exit(2)` code in its own class and stub or mock it out instead of calling that code directly.  This way, *in your test* it won't really exit, but you'll know that in a production environment it will.

If you don't know how to go about this (mock or stub), you should learn more about [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Now you're half done.  The other half is to use dependency injection to mock out `clothBrandQuery`.  Make it so that its `getClothBrandMethod` throws an exception no matter what.  Then you will go down this path. A good mocking framework to use is [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Comment: Yes, I did that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use System.exit() in that method, only use it in a main method and then throw an exception in mapThisBrands:

```
public class MapBrand implements SomeInterface{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapBrand map = new MapBrand();
        ClothBrand clothBrand = this.getClothBrand();
        try
        {
            map.mapThisBrands(clothBrand);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }

    public Brand mapThisBrands(final ClothBrand clothBrand) {

        Brand brand = new Brand();
        try{
            defaultBrand = clothBrandQuery.getClothBrandMethod(ProjectConstants.DEFAULT_BRAND_KEY);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.fatal("Database error occurred retrieving default cloth brands", e);
        }
        if(defaultBrand != null && defaultBrand != clothBrand){
            brand.setBrandName(clothBrand.getBrandName());
            brand.setCompanyName(clothBrand.getCompanyName());
            brand.setBackgroundColor(clothBrand.getBackgroundColor());
        }
        else{
            brand.setBrandName(defaultBrand.getBrandName());
            brand.setCompanyName(defaultBrand.getCompanyName());
            brand.setBackgroundColor(defaultBrand.getBackgroundColor());
        }
    }
}
```

And your test

```
public class MapBrandTestCase {

    @Test (expected = java.lang.Exception.class)
    public void databaseFailureShouldRaiseException()
    {
        Query clothBrandQuery = Mockito.mock(Query.class);
        when(clothBrandQuery.getClothBrandMethod(any())).thenThrow(new Exception());
        MapBrand mapBrand = new MapBrand(...);
        mapBrand.mapThisBrands(aBrand);
    }

}
```